# System of multiple inequalities

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations, functional-inequalities

in a Math class we are currently working with Farka's Lemma in order to determine if systems of equations have a solution. In order to do this we need to often find out if systems of multiple inequalities have solutions.

One such example is:

$\ x   +z+r≥\theta$

$\ x +y+r≥\theta$

$\ y   +z+r≥\theta$

$\ -y   -z-r≥\theta$

$\ 2x+2y   +2z+1<\theta$

In this case I was told that  there is a solution to this system, however I was wondering if there is a general approach I can use to determining if such a system has a solution. In order to use the parkas Lemma I don't need a specific solution, just if there is one or not.

Thank you very much a already in advance,

Marcel

Comment: I have solved your system with Mathematica. Do you want to see the solutions?

Comment: Hello Dr Graubner, yes please if that is possible it were greatly appreciated!

Comment: But it's a lot!

Comment: ahh I that case it's fine, but are there any general tricks or approaches I can use to solve systems like these, where a graphic approach is not possible?